# why the following jquery code does not work in tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

I have the following snippet of code to be executed by Tampermonkey in chrome on the website http://www.thefreedictionary.com/abnormally

I tried it standalone in the page and it works but it does not work through Tampermonkey.

The code is as follows:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       linkify span href
// @namespace  http://use.i.E.your.homepage/
// @version    0.1
// @description  enter something useful
// @match      http://www.thefreedictionary.com/*
// @require    http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js
// @copyright  2012+, You
// @grant      GM_log
// ==/UserScript==
//alert("hello");

jQuery(document).ready (Greasemonkey_main);

function Greasemonkey_main ()
{  
   alert("hjello");

   jQuery("span.hvr").each(function () { jQuery(this).wrap('<a href="/' + jQuery(this).text() + '" style="text-decoration:none;color:inherit" target="_blank"></a>')})
}
```

To check I also put an alert, the alert works, but not the jquery one line of code .

No clue why . please help .

**Note :**

What this one line code does ?

It just wraps every span tag in the page with an anchor tag .

How to try out that code in that page ?

add the script tag of jQuery link and then execute that one line from console and it will work .

Comment: Did you check if you come into each loop? with console.log or something?

Comment: No . But that does not mean that the line is wrong . to prove it . paste the following code as bookmark on that loaded page javascript:var jq = document.createElement('script'); jq.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"; document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq); and then execute jQuery("span.hvr").each(function () { jQuery(this).wrap('<a href="/' + jQuery(this).text() + '" style="text-decoration:none;color:inherit" target="_blank"></a>')}) it works as expected ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `span.hvr` links are generated dynamically: when the page loads, they do not exist, but then a script generates them sometime later.

So for your script to work, it should wait for `span.hvr` elements to be present first, before doing anything further.

The following modified script should work:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       linkify span href
// @namespace  http://use.i.E.your.homepage/
// @version    0.1
// @description  enter something useful
// @match      http://www.thefreedictionary.com/*
// @require    http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js
// @copyright  2012+, You
// @grant      GM_log
// ==/UserScript==
//alert("hello");

jQuery(document).ready(Greasemonkey_main);

function Greasemonkey_main ()
{  
    var isReady = jQuery("span.hvr").length > 0;

    if (!isReady) {
        setTimeout(Greasemonkey_main, 500);
        return;
    }

    jQuery("span.hvr").each(function () {         
        jQuery(this).wrap('<a href="/' + jQuery(this).text() + '" style="text-decoration:none;color:inherit" target="_blank"></a>')
    });
}
```

If there are pages in which it is possible to have no `span.hvr` elements, then you should make the script a bit smarter – stop retrying after 5-10 seconds for example.

Comment: Ya . Thank you very much. That works .I am confused ... does jquery .ready not ensure that everything was loaded? so script can run asynchronously ?

Comment: so do you mean to say that a javascript file is loaded and thats all , and the script can run thereafter and that will not be accounted in the jquery ready ?

Comment: `jQuery.ready` fires as soon as the DOM is ready. A site might run some scripts of its own after the DOM is ready or even well after that. In this case, thefreedictionary.com is running a script that creates the span.hvr elements after your script is run. So your script should continuously check and wait for the span.hvr elements to be present before doing anything else.